# Is there a way to provide environment variables to a VSTS CI npm task?

Tags: node.js, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Essentially, I need a way to inject environment variables for my app since I don't want to check a .env file into my repo. I was hoping to run something like `API_URL=api.example.com npm run build`, but it looks like you can't prepend things before the task command.

Is there a way to do this or is there a better way to create environment variables for a node app hosted in Azure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add some build variables to the build definition and then reference those in your build steps somewhere. For example, for your `API_URL` add a build variable with the same name and value. If you need the variable to be secret for any reason (passwords, etc.) just click the lock icon next to the value field.

[image]

Then add a new cmd task to your build and move it to the top to set your environment variables before you start your build. The way you reference the build variables is like this...

```
set API_URL=$(Build.API_URL)
```

In the UI it will look like this:

[image]

I added two cmd tasks to a test build just to show that it is working. The first one is used to set the environment variable and then I used the second to dump all the environment variables so I could see them. You can see in the build logs that it worked.

[image]

If you want to reference the build variables using something other than the command line you can find examples of the different ways to reference build variables [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?view=vsts&tabs=batch). There are also examples of how to use secret variables on that page.

EDIT:

Since you have some concerns about it not being available in your node app I tested it out in the console real quick to show that it will definitely work.

[image]

Comment: That works for adding it to the build environment, but I need this environment variable accessible via `process.env.API_URL` from within the node app.

Comment: Yeah, it should work as long as node is a capability of the build agent you are using. Which it should be since they have npm tasks as an option.

Comment: I added a screenshot of me testing it out on my local machine to my post. It shows that it will work.

Comment: You actually don't need to re-set them via the command line. If they're set as build variables (and not secret) then they should show up in `process.env`

Comment: This says that the variable only lasts as long as the cmd process. https://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: @Ian, yes that's true. I only did it this way to show one solution that's possible. If you set them as build variables as phillyslick commented above, they will get set for every single build that executes.

Answer (score 0):

Using yaml config you can switch to script task and then do something like this:

```yaml
- script: 'npm run'
  workingDirectory: 'src'
  displayName: 'npm run'
  env:
    { API_URL: 'api.example.com' }
```

Answer (score -1):

[tehbeardedone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2140747/tehbeardedone)'s answer is great for the build machine, and the answer is similar for when running your app in an Azure app service, which I'm thinking is what you really need. This is for if you need your access to these `.env` files just previous to or after your app has started (post build).

1. To the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com) we go.
2. Navigate to your app service.
3. Click "Configuration" under the "Settings" heading.

For each of the variables you'll need during a production run of your app you'll need to:

4. Click "New application setting"
5. Paste the name of the variable (exactly as it appears in your `.env`) into the "Name" field.
6. Similarly, paste the value of the variable into the next field.
7. Check the "deployment slot setting" checkbox. As nebulous as this field is, it's necessary. When I didn't do this, the app didn't have access to this variable after running the start command.

Restart your app. If you deployment when well, then your app should have access to the variables add in the manner specified above.